# Removing NA rows raster

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster with rows of NA that I want to remove in R. The rows are not on the edge of the raster, so I tried to use `crop` and `trim` but I didn't manage. Could someone give some tips please?
Here the file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6-UFgI67v99c3ZhUFp0eWpzOGM

Comment: Give a reproducible example, edit your question!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how that would make sense, conceptually. For a matrix, perhaps, but a raster does not have missing rows (even if the data might be stored in a sparse form, it would still know about them.)

Here is your problem:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r[3:4, ] <- NA
```

You might think that this would do it:

```
rr <- is.na(r)
i <- which(rowSums(rr) != ncol(rr))
x <- r[i, ,drop=FALSE]
```

But that does not do what you want, because the raster returned would not be valid. I suppose you could use `i` in a loop and create a list of RasterLayer objects.

Finally, you can create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, which essentially is a sparse raster like this:

```
  x <- as(r, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')
```

But whether that is useful or not depends on what next you want to do with `x`

Comment: Thank you Robert for your suggestion!